# Static variable for optimization

Tags: php, optimization, static-variables

I'm wondering if I can use a static variable for optimization:

```
public function Bar() {
    static $i = moderatelyExpensiveFunctionCall();
    if ($i) {
        return something();
    } else {
        return somethingElse();
    }
}
```

I know that once `$i` is initialized, it won't be changed by by that line of code on successive calls to `Bar()`.  I *assume* this means that `moderatelyExpensiveFunctionCall()` won't be evaluated every time I call, but I'd like to know for certain.

Once PHP sees a static variable that has been initialized, does it skip over that line of code?  In other words, is this going to optimize my execution time if I make a lot of calls to `Bar()`, or am I wasting my time?

Comment: Why not try it? It's a pretty simple change.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I find it easier to do something like the code below. That way the caching is done globally instead of per implementation of the function.

```
function moderatelyExpensiveFunctionCall()
{
   static $output = NULL;
   if( is_null( $output ) ) {
     //set $output
   }
   return $output;
}
```

Comment: Good call.  That's where the real problem lies.  It's an older piece of code that could probably use the optimization check.

Comment: A side question: Isn't using many (local) static variables, specific to an individual function causing overhead on RAM (since they will be kept in memory until the script executes fully) or are all variables kept in memory in PHP?

Comment: @ColorWP.com Yes this basically define a memory leak, but that's the point. This is similar to the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 2):

`static $i = blah()` won't compile, because php doesn't allow expressions and function calls in static initializers. You need something like

```
function foo() {
   static $cache = null;

   if(is_null($cache)) $cache = expensive_func();

   do something with $cache
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work in your (quite simple) case:

```
function your_function() {
    static $output;

    if (!isset($output)) {
       $output = 'A very expensive operation';
    }

    return $output;
}
```

As for a global caching mechanism, you may use a method similar to [this one](http://developer.teradata.com/blog/neilotoole/2009/06/a-simple-php-global-static-caching-mechanism).

Answer (score 0):

Here is quite shorter approach:

```
function stuff()
{
    static $smthg = []; // or null, or false, or something else
    if ($smthg) {
        return $smthg;
    }

    // filling $smthg goes here 
    // with a lot of 
    // code strings

    return $smthg;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

How about:

```
if (!isset($i))
{
    static $i = moderatelyExpensiveFunctionCall();
}
```

Comment: I tested that.  `isset()` seems to always return false.

Comment: $i is never going to be set before that, so the condition will never execute